# How to describe dynamic form data using OpenAPI (Swagger)?

Tags: swagger, multipartform-data, openapi

I'm trying to create an OpenAPI definition for this `multipart/form-data` request:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:1234/api/v1/Submit \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -H 'sessionkey: kjYgfORsZ0GeiCls0FcR7w==' \
  -F item1=abc \
  -F item2=def
  -F item3=ghi
  ...
```

My API definition is like this:

```yaml
post:
  consumes:
    - multipart/form-data
  produces:
    - application/json
  parameters:
    - in: formData
      name: item1
      type: string
    - in: formData
      name: item2
      type: string
```

It works fine with fixed fields in formData.

However, my form data will be dynamic, and I need to be able to send arbitrary keys and values.

I tried changing form parameters to use an array and `additionalProperties`, but it does not produce the desired result:

```yaml
- in: formData
  schema:
  additionalProperties:
    type: object

...

- in: formData
  type: array
  items:
    type: string
```

Is it possible to define dynamic formData with different keys and values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic form data can be defined using **OpenAPI 3.0** but not OpenAPI 2.0 (Swagger 2.0). OpenAPI 2.0 only supports fixed key names in form data.

In OpenAPI 3.0, you can describe dynamic form data using a schema with `additionalProperties`:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.2
...
servers:
  - url: 'http://localhost:1234/api/v1'
paths:
  /Submit:
    post:
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              # Object properties correspond to form fields
              type: object
              additionalProperties:
                type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
```

When testing the request in Swagger UI, enter the fields names and values in the JSON format:

```
{
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2",
  "field3": "value3"
}
```

Swagger UI will send these values as individual form fields:

[image: Sending dynamic form data in Swagger UI]

Comment: Is there a way to express arbitrary keys for multipart/form-data and `format: binary` to allow the user to arbitrary keyed file upload? I tried with `additionalProperties` but it didn't work. It just thought they were strings. Ignored the `format: binary`.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai `additionalProperties: {type: string, format: binary}` is the correct way to define your use case in OAS 3.0. This looks like a tooling issue. File an enhancement request or bug report with the tool where it didn't work.