# Swagger 2.0 x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I would like to define an endpoint using swagger 2.0 that consumes **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**  .

The passed parameters can have different names and be of different types.
How should I define this in the yaml? I am playing with this the whole day and cannot figure it out.
Everything I've found in the documentation is that I have to use 'parameters' but I don't know how to resolve the random number of parameters and their names.

As an example, I would like both queries to work:

First curl:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://localhost:8080/contact/123456789' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'name=random value' \
--data-urlencode 'Email=randomValue' \
--data-urlencode 'address=random' \
--data-urlencode 'surname2=123' \
--data-urlencode 'surname=random'
```

Second curl:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://localhost:8080/contact/123456789' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'car=bmw' \
--data-urlencode 'house=small'
```

And invalid YAML - but I cannot figure out how to solve my issue.

```
paths:
  /contact/{phone}:
    post:
      consumes:
        - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: formData
          name: form_data
          description: Body for submitting the contact
          required: false
          type: string
        - in: path
          name: phone
          description: phone number
          required: true
          type: string
```

Could you assist me?

Comment: See the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49877736/113116) and replace `multipart/form-data` with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Unfortunately this can only be defined using OpenAPI 3.0 but not in 2.0.